# Check my solution to system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following system of equations that I wanted to solve:

$$
2x_1+12x_2+16x_3=24\\
7x_1+6x_2+4x_3=18\\
3x_1+2x_2+8x_3=32\\
9x_1+5x_2+10x_3=14
$$

I tried arranging into matrix form:

$$
AX=b
$$

where

$$
A=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 12 & 16\\
7 & 6 & 4\\
3 & 2 & 8\\
9 & 5 & 10
\end{array}
\right]

,X =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{array}
\right]

,b=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
24\\
18\\
32\\
14
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I then tried to solve for $X$ using:

$$
X=A^+b
$$

where $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$, and obtained

$$
X=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{43146}{52789}\\
\frac{-49025}{52789}\\
\frac{235293}{105578}\\
\end{array}
\right]

=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0.817329368\\
-0.928697267\\
2.228617704\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Just to check my solution, I tried solving the system in another way using an iterative method on the computer and obtained the solution:

$$
X^*=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0.8173293681\\
-0.9286972669\\
2.228617705\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I thought that since both methods gave pretty much the same answer for the unknown matrix, it would be correct, however, $AX^*$ (or $AX$) is not even close to b:

$$
AX^*=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
26.1481747999999996\\
9.06359279399999984\\
18.4235351999999999\\
24.9986550200000010
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Normally, any of these methods work for me but in this case, I'm not sure.  I always thought that iterative methods would yield the best possible solution while the analytic solution for $X$ in $AX=b$ would give a more-or-less "exact" solution.  So I would understand if $X^*$ is as close to the proper solution as an iterative method can get but I don't understand why the analytic solution for $AX=b$ would be as equally off the mark.

I'm not good at being able to just "look" at equations and tell if or what kind of solution exists, so I was hoping if someone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong and/or if there is a more proper solution.  Like if there is actually no solution, is this the sort of thing that happens when you try to solve $AX=b$ either analytically or numerically?

Thanks!

Comment: Um, what's wrong with simply applying Gauss elimination? Is there any reason for using such heavy machinery?

Answer (score 3):

You have a over-determined system i.e. $4$ equations with $3$ unknowns. Hence, you cannot hope to get a unique solution unless $b \in \text{columnspace}(A)$.

In your case, $b$ doesn't belong to the column space of $A$. The solution you get $x^* = A^{+}b$ is the least square solution i.e. $x^{*} = \arg \min_{x} \|Ax-b\|_2$.

Comment: If it's full column rank, the least squares solution is unique though.